# <td> appending outside </tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a table, that displays data from loop and the whole row is being appended. The code is working fine, its just when I inspect element I notice that the `<td>` is outside `<tr>`, how can I fix it.

hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
var dataNum = 10;

for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

  $('table tbody').append('<tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>');
    } else if (j == 1) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000) + '</td>');
    }
  }
  $('table tbody').append('</tr>');

}



function todayDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('');
}

function deci(number) {
  var num = null;
  if (number < 10) {
    num = '000' + number;
  } else if (number > 9 && number < 100) {
    num = '00' + number;
  } else if (number > 99 && number < 1000) {
    num = '0' + number;
  } else {
    num = number;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```css
table th, table td{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th>Random</th>
    </tr>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are appending `tr` and `td` both to `tbody`. You need to append `td` to `tr`

```
for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

  $('table tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      $('table tbody tr:last').append('<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>');
    } else if (j == 1) {
      $('table tbody tr:last').append('<td>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000) + '</td>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
$('table tbody').append('<td>'...
```

is appending `td`s to the `tbody`.

Try creating the `tr` first, appending it to the `tbody`, and then append `td`s to the `tr`:

```js
var dataNum = 10;

for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

  const $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  $('table tbody').append($tr);
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      $tr.append('<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>');
    } else if (j == 1) {
      $tr.append('<td>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000) + '</td>');
    }
  }

}



function todayDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('');
}

function deci(number) {
  var num = null;
  if (number < 10) {
    num = '000' + number;
  } else if (number > 9 && number < 100) {
    num = '00' + number;
  } else if (number > 99 && number < 1000) {
    num = '0' + number;
  } else {
    num = number;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```css
table th, table td{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th>Random</th>
    </tr>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the following line.

`$('table tbody').append('<tr>');` This actually appends the tr into the DOM. So basically, `<tr></tr>` gets autocompleted since browser is smart and tries to ensure valid HTML DOM structure. What you should ideally do is create a string that stores entire DOM structure you need and append it at the end since DOM manipulations are slow.

```js
var dataNum = 10;
var str='';
for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

str += '<tr>';

  
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      str += '<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>';
    } else if (j == 1) {
      str+= '<td>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000) + '</td>';
    }
  }
  
  str += '</tr>';
  


}
  $('table tbody').append(str);



function todayDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('');
}

function deci(number) {
  var num = null;
  if (number < 10) {
    num = '000' + number;
  } else if (number > 9 && number < 100) {
    num = '00' + number;
  } else if (number > 99 && number < 1000) {
    num = '0' + number;
  } else {
    num = number;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```css
table th, table td{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th>Random</th>
    </tr>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: glad to be of help!!